# How to select a value in a selectbox with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a multiselect dropdown box and a input as below:

```
<select name="offer_type"  multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Hot Offer</option>
    <option value="2">Best Offer</option>
    <option value="3">Special / Festival Offer</option>
    <option value="4">Side Offer</option>
    <option value="5">Top Offer</option>
    <option value="6">Megha classified Offers</option>
    <option value="7">Buy One / Get One Offer</option>
    <option value="8">Inagural Offer</option> 
</select>

<input type="text" name="offer" value="" />
```

Now I want the selected value of **offer_type** in **offer** without page refresh. with Jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it for you, you don't need any PHP, just jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="offer_type"]').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('input[name="offer"]').val(selectedValue);
  });

});
```

For the multiple select, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="offer_type"]').click(function() {
    var selectedValsAsString = '';
    $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
        selectedValsAsString += $(this).val()+' ';
    });
    $('input[name="offer"]').val(selectedValsAsString);
  });

});
```

This will display your answers in the text field separated by a space.

Comment: Hi, Thanx for ur reply.I guess the above jquery is for single select option. If i have to choose multiple select option, Then how it will be?

Comment: Thanks a lot, both single and multiple select option are working.

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of the form fields:

```
$(function() {

      $('select[name="offer_type"]').change(function() {

      document.write(
      'offer type: ' + $('select[name="offer_type"]').serialize() + '<br />' +     
      'offer name: ' + $('input[name="offer"]').val()
      );

    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the rply. Can you do it without click function with multiple select option.