# one radio button will be selected at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsp page which shows the radio button content(on clicking it,select box will appear ) of a table.But here I'm unable select one radio button(with select box) at a time.I'm showing you the code.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('select1000').style.display=(this.checked)?'inline':'none';" name="license" value="1000"> 1-1000</td>
<td>
<div id="select1000" style="display: none">
<select id="">    
<option test="l25" value="25">25</option>
<option test="l100" value="100">100</option>

</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('select3000').style.display=(this.checked)?'inline':'none';" name="license" value=""> 1001-3000</td>
<td>
<div id="select3000" style="display: none">
<select id="">
<option test="l1001" value="1001">1001</option>
<option test="l1075" value="1075">1075</option>

</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('select5000').style.display=(this.checked)?'inline':'none';" name="license" value=""> 3001-5000</td>
<td>
<div id="select5000" style="display: none">
<select id="">
<option test="l3001" value="3001">3001</option>
<option test="l3075" value="3075">3075</option>

</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Where I am going wrong ..... any valuable input will be appreciated.

Comment: `style.display` s|b `style.display=`?

Comment: @Bob that's a minor mistake at the time of posting the Question,still radio button is not selected one at a time,I have edited.

Comment: do you want to hide the corresponding `div` its select is not selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to change the input element's name:

```
<td><input type="radio" onclick="change(this, 'select1000')" name="license[1]" value="1000"> 1-1000</td>
```

and create a function:

```
function change(t, div){

    var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    var radios = document.getElementsByName("license[1]"); 

        for (var i = 0, radio; radio = radios[i]; i++) {
            if (!radio.checked) {
                if(ele[i].id != div){
                    ele[i].style.display = 'none';               
                }
            }else{
               document.getElementById(div).style.display='inline';                
            }
        }

}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3NjpC/) you can see an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex for your answer,I found that where I made the mistake.One more thing is that I want update(i.e. submit this value to the database) this value(jsp page) ans want to show the value after updating(like it will appear on the page) without refreshing it,could you tell me little bit how to proceed

Comment: @Vivekanand yes you should do with ajax, when for example submit the form you can update the page retrieving data after success.

Comment: ,if this selectbox(after being selected) value I want to put in a textbox,I am doing this $("#text2").val($("#text1").val(); but not working.Any input

Comment: @Vivekanand , i'm sorry but I'm away, I respond via mobile phone, anyway check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353743/how-to-select-a-value-in-a-selectbox-with-jquery is an example how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this immediate reply

Comment: Hi Alex, I want to put text1 value in text2,any suggestion    <tr><td><input type="text" id="text1" name="customer" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" id="text2" name="key" value=""></td>
</tr>

Comment: I solved it : $("#text1").keyup(function(){
    $("#text2").val($(this).val());

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your parenthesis:

```
document.getElementById('select5000').style.display =  (this.checked ? 'inline':'none');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but I think the code will not working in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your inputs

```
<input type="radio" onchange="hideElem(this,'select1000')" name="license" value="1000">
<input type="radio" onchange="hideElem(this,'select3000')" name="license" value="">
<input type="radio" onchange="hideElem(this,'select5000')" name="license" value="">
```

and the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideElem(self,divId){
        var divs = ['select1000','select3000','select5000'];
        if(self.checked){
           for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++){
                if (divs[i] === divId){
                    document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'inline';
                } else{
                    document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'none';
                }
           }
        }
    }        
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uDy7R/2/)

Comment: if this selectbox(after being selected) value I want to put in a textbox,I am doing this $("#text2").val($("#text1").val(); but not working.Any input

Comment: you need to put a `class` or `id` selector for the `select boxes`. If you going to use class it's easier. Listen to the change event like this `$('.select').change(function(){$('#text1').val($(this).val());});`

Answer (score 1):

because when you click an input(radio), `this` is the current radio and you don't know the previous one, you need to record the previous select, use jQuery, code like:

```
(function () {
    var oldSel = null;
    $('input:radio').click(function () {
        // get the current select
        var sel = $('#select' + this.value);
        // show current select
        sel.show();
        // if old select is exist, hide it
        oldSel && oldSel.hide();
        // store the current select when radio on click
        oldSel = sel;
    })​;
})();​
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b24dt/)